# Patch function adding new rows to my SharePoint list instead of updating the targeted columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, microsoft-forms

The code below looks for the ID and then updates the number of items in the columns (No. Boots Distribution, No. Hats Distribution and No.Coverall Distribution) the data is updated by selecting a value from the drop down boxes in the app.

```
Patch(
    'PPE Test List',
    LookUp(
        'PPE Test List',ID=varRecord2.ID
        ),
        {'No. Boots Distribution':Dropdown1.Selected.Value,
        'No. Hats Distribution':Dropdown1_1.Selected.Value,
        'No.Coverall Distribution':Dropdown1_2.Selected.Value
        }
    );
```